# How to implement class object types that derive from parent class using UML class diagram

Tags: c++, oop, uml

I m learning C++ by creating simple traffic light logic using classes. In which I found this UML diagram and I want to create object types based on this. However, I created the TrafficLight class object struggling to understand control class logic part.

---

EDIT

To me, I just want to create traffic light for N, W, S and E. I can set light individually.  Perhaps I want to deviate from the UML. I just want to learn an efficient way to do that, any help appreciated. I see UML operations overlap with constructors.

---

This is the UML image I m implementing in C++

[image]

I don't understand the control object part. What I understood is control is directly associated with TrafficLight class.

Added the detailed object diagram

[image]
In which each UML arrows shows 1.1 that I don't know what it means?

Here do I need to have class control with the interface name N,W,E,S or just four class instance is enough?

From this UML how can I implement the control class that has four objects N,W,E,S?

---

This is my code, use -std=c++11 compiler flag.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
    
class TrafficLight {
  public:
    enum light { red, amber, green};

    // Setting the light by default red
    TrafficLight(light=red){
      cout << "constructed" << '\n';
    } // Default constructor

    // light state()  {
    //   std::cout << "Setting the t light" << '\n';
    // }

    void CreateLight(light l) {
      std::cout << "Creating lights" << '\n';
      // show on console which lights are turned on.
      if (l == light::green)
        cout << "Green ligh is ON" << '\n';
      else if (l == light::amber)
          cout << "Amber ligh is ON" << '\n';
      else
          cout << "Red ligh is ON" << '\n';
    }

    void SwitchLight(light l) {
      // switchLight operations executed
    }
  private:
    light _state;
};

// Wondering how to proceed here? Create Light control for west, east, north and south.
class Control : public TrafficLight {

};

int main(void) {
  /* code */
  std::cout << " Welcome to Trafficlight signaling system " << '\n';

  TrafficLight x(TrafficLight::green);
  TrafficLight::light l;

  // l = x.state();

  l = TrafficLight::green;
  x.CreateLight(TrafficLight::green);
  x.CreateLight(TrafficLight::red);
  x.CreateLight(TrafficLight::amber);
  x.CreateLight(TrafficLight::green);

  // run the derived class instance to create N,S,W,E
  // Control c_obj;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The diagram doesn't show inheritance, but composition (one `Control` controlling four different `TrafficLight`). Perhaps you should spend more time studying UML and the meaning of its different diagrams?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I m learning UML to understand the concept more. I want to learn how to create a control class object from the parent class where it has N,W, E and S objects.

Comment: Based on the diagram, your `Control` should have 4 instance of `TrafficLight`. Rather than having direct control to them, you would probably be calling `switchLight` and `createLight` from `switchControl` and `createLights`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep that clears my confusion, thanks for the lead. I create four instances of TrafficLight that is derived from Control class. Created four instances of Traffic light `Control North;` `Control East;` etc now I can access the TrafficLight object via Control object.

Comment: @danglingpointer No, you don't want 4 `Control`, instead you only want 1 `Control`. Check my code in the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the diagram you have, your `Control` would have 4 instance of `TrafficLight`.

While it doesn't say how exactly the would work, I would assume the intend is to call `switchLight` and `createLight` from `switchControl` and `createLights`, and you should not need to use `switchLight` and `createLight` directly.

Some code would be look somewhat like:

```
class TrafficLight
{
public:
    enum lightColor {red, amber, green};
    TrafficLight(lightColor color) : color(color){}
    void SwitchLight()
    {
        // Change to the next state.
        if(color == green) color = red;
        else ++color;
    }
private:
    lightColor color;
}

class Control
{
public:
    Control() : N(green), W(red), S(green), E(red){}
    void SwitchControl()
    {
        // All lights change to the next state.
        N.SwitchLight();
        W.SwitchLight();
        E.SwitchLight();
        S.SwitchLight();
    }
private:
    TrafficLight N, W, S, E;
}

int main()
{
    Control c; // N and S are green, W and E are red.
    c.SwitchControl(); // N and S are red, W and E are amber.
    c.SwitchControl(); // N and S are amber, W and E are green.
}
```

The only function you would want to call is the constructor for `Control`, and `SwitchControl()`.

Note that I didn't call the full name for `lightColor`s, where you would actually need to do that to make the code work. I also removed `Create` functions, as they are kind of overlapping with the ctors.

Comment: To me, I just want to create traffic light for N, W, S and E. I can set light individually.  Perhaps I want to deviate from the UML. I just want to learn an efficient way to do that. I see UML operations overlap with constructors.

Comment: @danglingpointer If you only want to create `TrafficLight`, then you wouldn't need `Control` at all. You can just construct them separately and use `TrafficLight::SwitchLight` to control each light individually. The idea about `Control` is to have a easy way to construct and control all lights at the same time.